# My strategy shall reveal you my name

Tags: knowledge, visual

[image]

Hint:

> Knowledge sphere is videogames

Hint 2:

> A part of the inferences from the images is slightly inappropriate.

Hint 3:

> A few images can be a bit misleading, ie easily read into something close, but different than what they are

Hint 4:

> Black to move

Comment: @JLee Not sure what steganography actually is, but no you don't need an editor at all.

Comment: @JLee After learning what steganography is, I removed it. Pictures are only there to lead you to words.

Comment: I think we could use another hint, especially if one of the images doesn't represent what you thought it did when you created the puzzle.

Comment: @SQLnoob Sure they do! Someone else added the steganography tag.

Comment: I'm talking about your comment where you mentioned that you were wrong about one of the images, the one you thought would be most helpful for solving the puzzle. That seems like a concerning issue if it isn't clarified.

Comment: @SQLnoob Got it, hint 4

Comment: is the broken image markdown intentional?

Comment: @MooseBoys No, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the images:

> The first image is of a soldier hanging out of a train window to kiss a girl. These soldiers were en route to the Korean War in 1950. They are "**part**"ing?
>
> The second image is of Winston Churchill giving the V for victory sign.  V is the roman numeral for **five**.
>
> The third image is of the actress Scarlett Johansson, perhaps most famous as Black Widow in the Marvel movies, but also a conspicuous body part...
>
> The fourth image is of a leg trap. In combination with the prior image - “**booby trap**”
>
> The fifth image is of a chessboard. With black to move, this is a **stalemate**.
>
> The sixth image is of a keyboard, with an arrow pointing to what others have correctly identified as the Escape key... however it appears to be a Dutch AZERTY keyboard, so the key actually says "Echap" if that's worth noting... but forget all that, it's just a **button**.

The solution:

> Put these together to get the quote "[Part Five: Booby-trap the stalemate button!](https://i1.theportalwiki.net/img/2/29/Wheatley_bw_finale04_button_press01.wav)" which is a famous line spoken by the character **[Wheatley](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Wheatley)** as he reveals his strategy in the final battle of the incredible puzzle video game **[Portal 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_2)**.

Comment: You have enough correct observations that if a certain combination of them is applied on a browser search it is possible to figure out the answer without knowing the subject in the first place. Despite the fact that judging from your profile you should be ashamed you haven't found it yet ;P

Comment: omg you're right, i can't believe I didn't get that sooner!  In my defense it's been at least a few years since I last played the game.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, whose strategy is that? Not too hard considering it's your icon, lol.

Comment: Answer updated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps

> Batman

Pictures (l-r, t-b)

> The first forms the image of a "T" using people
>  The second forms an image of a "V" using Churchill
>  The third is Scarlett Johansson, or the "Black Widow" in the marvel universe
>  The fourth is a "trap"
>  The fifth looks like the letter "I" using a chess position which could be a draw or win for white, depending on whose move it is
>   The last is an arrow to the "escape" key on a keyboard

Which gives

> TV Black Widow trap I escape

Reasoning

> In season 2, episodes 55-56 of the 1960s TV show "Batman", Tallulah Bankhead plays the Black Widow and traps Batman in a web full of black widow spiders.  He escapes (spoiler alert!).

However

> I don't see how the title relates to this

Comment: Nice try, but no. However, to honour your try, I'm gonna say this in rot13: Bar bs lbhe nanylfrf bs n cvpgher pbagnvaf n snyfr fgngrzrag. Vagrerfgvatyl, va zl bcvavba, guvf cvpgher vf gur zbfg urycshy va qrgrezvavat gur nafjre pbzcnerq gb gur bguref.

Comment: Nyfb: vg frrzf vg jnf zlfrys jub jnf jebat naq abg lbh. Varkcrevrapr jvgu gur fhowrpg qbrf guvf. Vs lbh pna fgvyy hfr gurfr pbzzragf nf n gvc....